# How can I select specific columns/properties when using AzureTableStorage Serilog sink?

Tags: serilog

Currently my Serilog logger configuration is like the following:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel
    .Debug()
    .WriteTo
    .AzureTableStorageWithProperties(CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Currently the logger logs bunch of properties in the table storage. I would like to select specific properties to log. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the properties specified in the various Serilog Log methods will be rendered as table properties.

[image]